# Updating DATABASE using datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2017

am newbie in vb.net. i use visual studio 2017 and sqlserver 2008
i have a datagridview that has been filled from a database using combobox as filter. 
now i want to update my database by adding or deleting data in mydatagridview using a button named edit
please help me :'(

*****here the code that i have used to fill my datagridviw

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox3_SelectedvalueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox3.SelectedValueChanged
    'filling datagridview using cmbbx 3'
    Cn.Open()
    rq = "select * from [cutting software].dbo.vehicule"
    rq1 = "select * from [cutting software].dbo.tissu"
    rq2 = "select* from [cutting software].dbo.projet"
    rq3 = "select * from [cutting software].dbo.kit_cover"
    rq4 = "select * from [cutting software].dbo.[Plan de coupe]"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(rq, Cn)
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand(rq1, Cn)
    da1 = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd1)
    Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand(rq2, Cn)
    da2 = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd2)
    Dim cmd3 As New SqlCommand(rq3, Cn)
    da3 = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd3)
    Dim cmd4 As New SqlCommand(rq4, Cn)
    da4 = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd4)
    Cn.Close()
    If ComboBox3.SelectedItem = "vehicule" Then
        ds = New DataSet
        dt = New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
        da.Fill(ds, "vehicule")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        dt = ds.Tables("vehicule")
    ElseIf ComboBox3.SelectedItem = "tissu" Then
        dt1 = New DataTable
        da1.Fill(dt1)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt1
        dt1 = ds.Tables("tissu")
    ElseIf ComboBox3.SelectedItem = "projet" Then
        dt2 = New DataTable
        da2.Fill(dt2)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt2
        dt2 = ds.Tables("projet")
    ElseIf ComboBox3.SelectedItem = "kit_cover" Then
        dt3 = New DataTable
        da3.Fill(dt3)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt3
        dt3 = ds.Tables("kit_cover")
    ElseIf ComboBox3.SelectedItem = "plan coupe" Then
        dt4 = New DataTable
        da4.Fill(dt4)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt4
        dt4 = ds.Tables("Plan de coupe")
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub edit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles edit.Click
    Cn.Open()
    cmdb = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
    da.Update(ds, "vehicule")
    Cn.Close()
End Sub
```

**** here the code that i have used to update the database

```vb
Private Sub edit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles edit.Click
    If ComboBox3.SelectedItem = "vehicule" Then
        Cn.Open()
        cmdb = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
        da.Update(ds, "vehicule")
        Cn.Close()
    ElseIf ComboBox3.SelectedItem = "tissu" Then
        Cn.Open()
        cmdb = New SqlCommandBuilder(da1)
        da1.Update(ds, "tissu")
        Cn.Close()
    ElseIf ComboBox3.SelectedItem = "projet" Then
        Cn.Open()
        cmdb = New SqlCommandBuilder(da2)
        da2.Update(ds, "projet")
        Cn.Close()
    ElseIf ComboBox3.SelectedItem = "kit_cover" Then
        Cn.Open()
        cmdb = New SqlCommandBuilder(da3)
        da3.Update(ds, "kit_cover")
        Cn.Close()
    ElseIf ComboBox3.SelectedItem = "plan coupe" Then
        Cn.Open()
        cmdb = New SqlCommandBuilder(da4)
        da4.Update(ds, "plan de coupe")
        Cn.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

the first code work correctly but i hve problem  in the second
when i run the second code it shows me this msg System.InvalidOperationException: 'Update unable to find TableMapping['vehicule'] or DataTable 'vehicule'.'

Comment: If you have a problem you should share what the problem is. [Edit] the question and show us what errors or messages you get, and/or what unexpected results you get.

Comment: if i run the code i have this message:                
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Update unable to find TableMapping['vehicule'] or DataTable 'vehicule'.'

Comment: If you have a problem you should: [EDIT] [Edit] [edit] the question and explain it there.

Comment: i edited the question hope it is clear . if there is something unclear i'll try to explain more .

Comment: It looks like you need to start with the fundamentals. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

You just have too much going on. Keep it simple. You are binding to a single table. You just need one select statement with the selected table name added on the end. A single DataAdapter and DataTable. The DataTable can update the database without going through the ComboBox dance again.

The Using blocks will ensure that you Connection is not only closed but disposed.

```vb
Private dt As DataTable
Private da As SqlDataAdapter
'**EDIT** move declare of rq to class level
Private rq As String

Private Sub ComboBox3_SelectedvalueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox3.SelectedValueChanged
    '**EDIT** moved declaration to Class level
    rq = "select * from [cutting software].dbo." & ComboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString
    dt = New DataTable
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(rq, cn)
        da.Fill(dt) 'If the connection is closed, the DataAdapter will open and close it for you
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub

Private Sub edit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles edit.Click
    Dim cmdb As New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
        '**EDIT** Add line to re-establish connection for adapter
        da.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(rq, cn)
        da.Update(dt)
    End Using
End Sub
```

**EDIT** Re-establish connection for the DataAdapter.

Comment: thank you for your reply i tried your code the datagridview was filled successfully  but for the update it shows me this message  :                   System.InvalidOperationException: 'The ConnectionString property has not been initialized

Comment: @hnd So sorry. I neglected to re-establish the connection property of the DataAdapter. Pleas see edits to my code.

Comment: thanx a lot Mary. i tried your code and it works correctly

Comment: am sorry @Mary  have not enough reputation

Comment: @hnd You always have enough reputation points to accept an answer. Not the up and down arrows which are for up votes and down votes. You click the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer to accept an answer.

Comment: i understand now

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Dim sCommand As SqlCommand
    Dim sAdapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim sBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder
    Dim sDs As DataSet
    Dim sTable As DataTable

    Private Sub load_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles load_btn.Click
        Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=pubs;Integrated Security=True"
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Stores"
        Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        connection.Open()
        sCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
        sAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sCommand)
        sBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(sAdapter)
        sDs = New DataSet()
        sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "Stores")
        sTable = sDs.Tables("Stores")
        connection.Close()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = sDs.Tables("Stores")
        DataGridView1.ReadOnly = True
        save_btn.Enabled = False
        DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect

    End Sub

    Private Sub new_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles new_btn.Click
        DataGridView1.[ReadOnly] = False
        save_btn.Enabled = True
        new_btn.Enabled = False
        delete_btn.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub delete_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles delete_btn.Click
        If MessageBox.Show("Do you want to delete this row ?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.Yes Then
            DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Index)
            sAdapter.Update(sTable)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub save_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles save_btn.Click
        sAdapter.Update(sTable)
        DataGridView1.[ReadOnly] = True
        save_btn.Enabled = False
        new_btn.Enabled = True
        delete_btn.Enabled = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

http://vb.net-informations.com/datagridview/vb.net_datagridview_database.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim DA As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
Dim cmdBldr As New SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(DA)

'Load DataGrid
  Private Sub BtnGet_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGet.Click
        Dim strQry As String = "SELECT *  FROM tblEVALUATION where ADVT_NO='" & cmbAdvtNo.Text & "' and SUBJECT_ID=" & cmbSubject.SelectedValue
        cmd.CommandText = strQry
        cmd.Connection = SQL._ConMSSql
        DA.SelectCommand = cmd
        DA = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(strQry, SQL._ConMSSql)
        ds.Clear()
        DA.Fill(ds)
        DTV.DataSource = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
        DTV.Visible = True
        DTV.Refresh()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        Dim recUpdated As Integer
        DA.UpdateCommand = cmdBldr.GetUpdateCommand
        recUpdated = DA.Update(ds)
        MsgBox("Record Updated=" & recUpdated & " Successfully...")
    End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).